# UIButton in UIWebView to previous/next article in my UITableViewController without back in her

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton, uitableview

I have two UIButton in my UIWebview and i want when i clicked on them previous/next article the WebView display the previous or next article without back in UITableView. But i don't know to do that.

It's a RSS feed application with a tableViewController witch store the articles of the feed and UIWebView witch display the content.

please help me :)

Comment: Two UIButtons inside a UIWebView? How? On top of them or through HTML? What do you exactly mean?

Comment: i have two UIButton on the WebView and i want to add IBAction to go at the previous or next articles witch are in my UITableViewController without, obviously, back in the tableView just clicked on buttons. My application work like this: i have an UITableViewController who store my articles when i click on any cell i display the content of the article in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
- (IBAction) webViewGoBack
{
    if ([webView canGoBack]) 
    {
        [webView goBack];
    }
}

- (IBAction) webViewGoForward
{
    if ([webView canGoForward]) 
    {
        [webView goForward];
    }
}
```